# Getting an error while trying to run a simple spark streaming kafka example

Tags: scala, spark-streaming

I am trying to run a simple kafka spark streaming example. Here is the error I am getting.

> 16/10/02 20:45:43 INFO SparkEnv: Registering OutputCommitCoordinator
>   Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:
>   scala.Predef$.$scope()Lscala/xml/TopScope$;   at
>   org.apache.spark.ui.jobs.StagePage.(StagePage.scala:44)     at
>   org.apache.spark.ui.jobs.StagesTab.(StagesTab.scala:34)     at
>   org.apache.spark.ui.SparkUI.(SparkUI.scala:62)  at
>   org.apache.spark.ui.SparkUI$.create(SparkUI.scala:215)    at
>   org.apache.spark.ui.SparkUI$.createLiveUI(SparkUI.scala:157)  at
>   org.apache.spark.SparkContext.(SparkContext.scala:443)  at
>   org.apache.spark.streaming.StreamingContext$.createNewSparkContext(StreamingContext.scala:836)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.streaming.StreamingContext.(StreamingContext.scala:84)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.streaming.api.java.JavaStreamingContext.(JavaStreamingContext.scala:138)
>     at com.application.SparkConsumer.App.main(App.java:27)

I am setting this example using the following pom. I have tried to find this missing scala.Predef class, and added the missing dependency for spark-streaming-kafka-0-8-assembly, and I can see the class when I explore this jar.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.kafka</groupId>
    <artifactId>kafka_2.11</artifactId>
    <version>0.8.2.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.kafka</groupId>
    <artifactId>kafka-clients</artifactId>
    <version>0.8.2.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
      <artifactId>spark-core_2.11</artifactId>
      <version>2.0.0</version>
      <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
      <artifactId>spark-streaming_2.11</artifactId>
      <version>2.0.0</version>
      <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
    <artifactId>spark-streaming-kafka-0-8_2.11</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.scala-lang</groupId>
    <artifactId>scala-library</artifactId>
    <version>2.11.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
    <artifactId>spark-streaming-kafka-0-8-assembly_2.11</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.0</version>
</dependency>
```

I have tried a simple spark word count example and it works fine. When I use this spark-streaming-kafka, I am having trouble. I have tried to lookup for this error, but no luck.

Here is the code snippet.

```
        SparkConf sparkConf = new SparkConf().setAppName("someapp").setMaster("local[2]");
        // Create the context with 2 seconds batch size
        JavaStreamingContext jssc = new JavaStreamingContext(sparkConf, new Duration(2000));

        int numThreads = Integer.parseInt(args[3]);
        Map<String, Integer> topicMap = new HashMap<String,Integer>();
        topicMap.put("fast-messages", 1);
        Map<String, String> kafkaParams = new HashMap<String,String>();
        kafkaParams.put("metadata.broker.list", "localhost:9092");
        JavaPairReceiverInputDStream<String, String> messages = 
        KafkaUtils.createStream(jssc,"zoo1","my-consumer-group", topicMap);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There seems to be problem when I used 2.11 of 0.8.2.0 kafka. After switching to 2.10 it worked fine.